# How to do multiple condition input validations with different print statements?

Tags: java, validation, input

I'm a beginner in Java and the problem that I've run into is I'm not sure how to chain input validation together so that the proper response to the user's incorrect input is given. For example, when the user enters something that's not a letter, the program does tell the user that what they've entered is not a letter, but if I then enter more than one letter, the program doesn't print out the correct response. It's based on whichever mistake the user makes first.

I appreciate all feedback.

```
String input;
final Pattern alphabet = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]$");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    
System.out.println("Enter a letter of the alphabet: ");
input = kb.nextLine();
    
    
while (!alphabet.matcher(input).matches())
{
    System.out.println("That's not a letter, try again.");
    input = kb.nextLine();
}
    
while (input.length() > 1 )
{
    System.out.println("Please enter only one letter");
    input = kb.nextLine();
}

kb.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do likes this: Make it become check condition in if and get the result

```
final Pattern alphabet = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]$");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

public void drive_main() {
    System.out.println("Enter a letter of the alphabet: ");
    String input = getInput();
    while (input == null) {
        input = getInput();
    }
}

public String getInput() {

    String result;
    result = kb.nextLine();
    if (!alphabet.matcher(result).matches()) {
        System.out.println("That's not a letter, try again.");
        return null;
    }
    if (result.length() > 1) {
        System.out.println("Please enter only one letter");
        return null;
    }
    return result;

}
```

OR you can assign you input to a new class package (input, error, and have an error or not) make it more flexible.

```
final Pattern alphabet = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]$");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

public void drive_main() {
    System.out.println("Enter a letter of the alphabet: ");
    InputSet input = getInput(kb.nextLine());
    while (input.isError) {
        System.out.println(input.errorMessage);
        input = getInput(kb.nextLine());
    }
}

public InputSet getInput(String input) {
    InputSet result = new InputSet(input, false, "");
    if (!alphabet.matcher(result.input).matches()) {
        result.errorMessage = "That's not a letter, try again.";
        result.isError = true;
    }
    if (result.input.length() > 1) {
        result.errorMessage = "Please enter only one letter";
        result.isError = true;
    }
    return result;
}

private class InputSet {

    String input;
    boolean isError;
    String errorMessage;

    InputSet() {

    }

    InputSet(String input, boolean isError, String errorMessage) {
        this.input = input;
        this.isError = isError;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

1st is you should not use the while loop to check the condition.
2nd design your program properly loop > verify error.
You should do more good practical and clean code than you can easily find the error. Try to use less loop as possible it will cause more error and the program memory using

Comment: The second solution is more fitting to what I'm looking for, as it needs to keep asking for the user to actually input something when they get it wrong, where the first solution does not do that.